# How to convert a result of ask to appropriate type?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I'm using `ask` (`?`) to get a value which is of type `Set[String]` from an Actor. However, the actor returns `Future[Any]`.

What is the correct way to convert this `Future[Any]` to `Future[Set[String]]`?

```
val result : Future[Any] = myactor ? GetSomeValue
//convert Future[Any] to Future[Set[String]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is method called `mapTo` available on Futures:

```
val result : Future[Set[String]] = (myactor ? GetSomeValue).mapTo[Set[String]]
```

It will raise an Exception if the cast is not successful. From the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future):

> Creates a new Future[S] which is completed with this Future's result if that conforms to S's erased type or a ClassCastException otherwise.

Comment: Then this new Future will be completed with that error. Internally this method just uses the normal `map` method. All it does is checking wether the cast will work. And as with normal map, the future gets completed with the original error.